# Using jQuery, how do I get the text value of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I retrieve the text between the href tag?

```
<a href="blah">GET THIS TEXT</a>
```

It is wrapped in this DOM:

```
<div class="c1">
   <div class="c2"><a href="#">GET THIS TEXT</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A better title for this might be: "Using jQuery, how do I get the text value of an element?". Href is an attribute, not a tag.

Answer (score 23):

You are looking for the [`text()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) property:

```
$('a', 'div.c2').text();
```

The reason `div.c2` is defined as the second argument is because it would then be the [`context`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) of the selector. By default jQuery searches the entire document when you use `$()`, by specifying `div.c2` it is only going to search inside of `<div>`'s with a class of c2.

Keeping this in mind, you could also rewrite the above like this:

```
$('div.c2 a').text();
```

Most people prefer this because it is the syntax that you would use to select this element in a CSS stylesheet. However, jQuery then has to figure that out. You could  even do:

```
$('div.c2').find('a').text();
```

However, I prefer the context method as I feel it is cleaner and marginally faster, not that it matters.

There is also the [`html()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Html) property, which  gets the contents, **including HTML**.

So if your link was like this:

```
<a href='#'><b>Hi There</b></a>
```

Then:

```
$('a').text(); // would return Hi There
$('a').html(); // would return <b>Hi There</b>
```

Comment: Note that you can write that also as $('div.c2 a').text(); It's not necessary to split it off into another function.

Comment: I know, but I very much prefer to help out jQuery do the parsing. I think it's cleaner to specify a context whenever possible than to just have a selector string.

Answer (score 4):

I think that [`.text()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) or [`.html()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) will work, depending on whether you don't or do want any markup that appears inside the tag.

```
var txt = $('div.c2 > a').text();

var html = $('div.c2 > a').html()
```