# Adding different classes to each list item name as class

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to add a class of each li items like [Adding different classes to each list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573042/adding-different-classes-to-each-list-item)

I used code from here [Adding different classes to each list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573042/adding-different-classes-to-each-list-item)

```
$(function () {

  $(".sd-list li").each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("class", "color" + index);
  });

});
```

It is add the class like color0, color1
But I want add a class of given attribute name like `<li>Brand</li>`
It is display the  `<li class"color-brand">Brand</li>`

Please let me know how can i do this becase am not want to add 0, 1, 2 I want the class as a name

Comment: how will you determine the name to use - is `<li class="color-brand">` because the text content of that element is `Brand`? i.e. `$(this).attr("class", "color-" + $(this).text().toLowerCase());` - though, this isn't ADDING the class it's SETTING the class - you want `$(this).addClass("color-" + $(this).text().toLowerCase());` maybe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jQuery, how do I get the text value of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754666/using-jquery-how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 way you can do it is like this:

```
$("ul li").addClass(function() {
  return `color-${$(this).text().toLowerCase()}`
})
```

Here we combine the text of the li with the prefix `color-` and add it to the class of the li.

**Demo**

```js
$("ul li").addClass(function() {
  return `color-${$(this).text().toLowerCase()}`
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Brand1</li>
  <li>Brand2</li>
  <li>Brand3</li>
</ul>
```